# yup date validation - Start Date must not be same as end date

Tags: javascript, validation, yup, dayjs

I am currently stuck on how to do validation with yup for same date.

Currently I am able to validate if endDate is not before startDate using :

```
schema = yup.object().shape({
  startDate: yup.date().min(new Date(),'Please choose future date'),
  endDate: yup
          .date()
          .min(
             yup.ref("startDate"),
             "End date has to be more than start date"
          ),
})
```

But it is not checking for same date.
I am well aware of this thread :  [Date range validation - Start Date must not be same as End Date in jquense / yup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807624/date-range-validation-start-date-must-not-be-same-as-end-date-in-jquense-yup) , but it is not solved yet and using momentjs. My company is strictly using dayjs for this project.

I hope you can help me with solution using JS or dayjs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
schema = yup.object().shape({
  startDate: yup.date().min(new Date(),'Please choose future date'),    
  endDate: yup
              .date()    
              .when('startDate',
                            (startDate, schema) => {
                                if (startDate) {
                                const dayAfter = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 86400000);
                              
                                    return schema.min(dayAfter, 'End date has to be after than start date');
                                  }
                              
                                  return schema;
                                
                            }),
})
```

Comment: this does not consider the same day time. How to include it?

Comment: "const dayAfter = new Date(startDate.getTime());"  this will solve the usage issue

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  startDate: Yup.date().required(),
  endDate: Yup.date().test(
    "same_dates_test",
    "Start and end dates must not be equal.",
    function (value) {
      const { startDate } = this.parent;
      return value.getTime() !== startDate.getTime();
    }
  ),
});
```